# Touchstart firing twice on mobile

Tags: android, jquery, mobile

I am having some trouble with a mobile menu. At first i had my code written like this which worked fine on desktop

```
$('#nav-icon3').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});

$('.menu-item').click(function(){
  $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
});
```

after uploading and checking on my mobile device via android chrome the click function was not working, so i tried using the touchstart.

```
$('#nav-icon3').on('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});

$('.menu-item').on('click touchstart', function(){
  $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
});
```

when touching the menu-item element, the toggle fires twice. Anyway I can prevent this from happening and let it only fire once?

Answer (score 0):

I think what is going on based on your question is that your event is propagating. What you can do is the stop the event from propagating by doing something like this.

```
$('.menu-item').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#nav-icon3').toggleClass('open');
});
```

More reference here:

https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

Using `e.preventDefault();` worked for me when I had the same issue as you.

```
$('#nav-icon3').on('touchstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```